# Which is better to use : A service or a translucent activity in Android?

Tags: android

I'm using a transparent activity as the MAIN,to test a certain variable, and depending on its value, the transparent Activity will intent a certain Activity.

Since the transparent activity will be paused after it's executed, i'm wondering if it's better to use a Service instead of the transparent Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

services are used for long runnig task to do in background like playing mp3 files. you can use 
activity . there is no problem in that . it will hardly take to move to next activity .

you can also use a application class.This class will always be executed once before staring the launcher activity. example

create a class

```
 public class MyApplication extends Application
    {
      @Override
      public void onCreate()
      {
        super.onCreate();

      // here check for your variable
//start your intent activity frokm here.
      }
```

in menifeast give name of your class.

```
<application android:name="com.myname.MyApplication"
 android:icon="@drawable/icon"
 android:label="@string/app_name"></application>
```

what you can do is create a launcher activity....in its onCreate method check your variables and start the intent and finish this activity in oncreate itself. this way it is correct.

Comment: I created MyApplication class and i removed the translucent activity from the manifest. The application is stopping because there aren't any activity as main activity.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass your own `MyApplication` class from android `Application` class. In `MyApplication.onCreate` you can then check the variable and launch the corresponding activity,

Comment: I don't have a MyApplication class (or i don't know where to find it). 
What i did is, i added <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> in the AndroidManifest.xml to launch the transparent Activity at first.

Answer (score 0):

`Service` is used for doing a background operation so that even if your `activity` loses focus the code runs without any problem. So it all depends on you, if your user close your `activity` while it is executing your code then go ahead and use it.

Comment: The transparent activity is executed only one time at launching,so i don't think the execution will be interrupted. Thank you

Comment: what i meant to say is if the use press a back button then you activity will be destroyed. You might wanna consider that.